# Find number of solutions to the equation $\sin(6\sin x)=\frac{x}{6}$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Find number of solutions to the equation $$\sin(6\sin x)=\frac{x}{6}.$$

By plotting it on any graphing software one is able to see instantly that it has $15$ solutions. However I am not able to work it out manually.

Let $f(x)=\sin(6\sin x)$

Period of $f(x)$ is obviously $2\pi$

$f'(x)=\cos(6\sin x)\cdot 6\cos x$

Putting $f'(x)=0$ to obtain points of maxima/minima is the tricky part.

$x=\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$ are quite obvious but $6\sin x=\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$ is difficult to get. After this it becomes even more confusing. Could there be a way out.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no faster technique than studying the function $6\sin(6\sin x) - x$ (i.e. zeros, extrema, convexity, etc.) manually as you did. Graphing the function does it in a quicker way for sure in the end.